# How can I tell when my apk has been updated in the Play store?

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-games, google-play-developer-api

I've been updating my apk a lot recently, since this is my first app and am seeing a lot of compatibility issues. In the developer console, Google tells me the new apk I have uploaded has almost instantly gone to "in prod" and the older version is "unpublished". However, in the play store the app is still showing version 1.0. This is strange because the first update I made was almost 12 hours ago now, so it should at least be showing 1.1, right? If these updates aren't going through instantly that would make a lot of sense as to why my app is still having compatibility issues.

My play store listing: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ali.ColorMatch2

Developer console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK3mV.jpg

EDIT: I'd also like to note I keep getting notifications that my update is live to the store but nothing is changing on the listing.

Comment: Seems to me that you are taking the wrong approach towards deploying for testing (I think that is what you are trying to accomplish, according to your questions). You don't need the apk to be on the Play Store in order to be tested. There are lots of free and paid beta testing services and even an official one [here](https://developer.android.com/distribute/engage/beta.html). I suggest you have a look

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same issue. 2 days ago I've upploaded a new version of my app and it was the same situation: it was saying "processing update" in the top right corner (developer console) and in APK it was written that the new version is availabe. Hovewer, in Google Play store there was an old version. After 26 hours I contacted google support but receive no answer and after one more day the new version of my app appeared on the Play store. So it took about 40 hours after publishing, so prepare to be patient :)

Comment: Oh jeez that does seem like an awful long wait, and I think I'm going to need to mess around with the compatible screens part of my android manifests a lot to get it to work as I like. So, since this app was just for practice for myself and it has 0 downloads (probably due to compatibility issues), what's stopping me from just uploading my new apk as a new app? I am also pressed for time, I'm submitting some time-sensitive applications and I would like to have this on my resume

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from doing that.